# Specific Instructions on Building POCO under C++ express

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, poco-libraries

Searching around stackoverflow, I found out that the POCO library build file is not compatible with Visual Studio Express, that it needs `devenv.exe`. Some answeres say to replace `devenv` with `vcexpress` is the buildwin.cmd. No one offers specific instructions. This is the buildwin.cmd:

```
@echo off
setlocal

rem
rem buildwin.cmd
rem
rem POCO C++ Libraries command-line build script 
rem for MS Visual Studio 2003 to 2010
rem
rem $Id: //poco/1.4/dist/buildwin.cmd#2 $
rem
rem Copyright (c) 2006-2010 by Applied Informatics Software Engineering GmbH
rem and Contributors.
rem
rem Original version by Aleksandar Fabijanic.
rem Modified by Guenter Obiltschnig.
rem
rem Usage:
rem ------
rem buildwin VS_VERSION [ACTION] [LINKMODE] [CONFIG] [PLATFORM] [SAMPLES] [DEVENV]
rem VS_VERSION: 71|80|90|100
rem ACTION:     build|rebuild|clean
rem LINKMODE:   static_mt|static_md|shared|all
rem CONFIG:     release|debug|both
rem PLATFORM:   Win32|x64|WinCE
rem SAMPLES:    samples|nosamples
rem DEVENV:     devenv|vcexpress
rem
rem VS_VERSION is required argument. Default is build all.

if not defined VCINSTALLDIR (
echo Error: No Visual C++ environment found.
echo Please run this script from a Visual Studio Command Prompt
echo or run "%%VSnnCOMNTOOLS%%\vcvars32.bat" first.
goto :EOF)

rem Change OPENSSL_DIR to match your setup
set OPENSSL_DIR=c:\OpenSSL
set OPENSSL_INCLUDE=%OPENSSL_DIR%\include
set OPENSSL_LIB=%OPENSSL_DIR%\lib\VC
set INCLUDE=%INCLUDE%;%OPENSSL_INCLUDE%
set LIB=%LIB%;%OPENSSL_LIB%

set POCO_BASE=%CD%
set PATH=%POCO_BASE%\bin;%PATH%

rem VS version {71|80|90|100}
if "%1"=="" goto usage
set VS_VERSION=vs%1

if "%7"=="" goto use_devenv
set BUILD_TOOL="%7"
goto use_custom
:use_devenv
set BUILD_TOOL=vcexpress
:use_custom

rem Action [build|rebuild|clean]
set ACTION=%2
if not "%ACTION%"=="build" (
if not "%ACTION%"=="rebuild" (
if not "%ACTION%"=="" (
if not "%ACTION%"=="clean" goto usage)))

if "%ACTION%"=="" (set ACTION="build")

rem Link mode [static|shared|both]
set LINK_MODE=%3
if not "%LINK_MODE%"=="static_mt" (
if not "%LINK_MODE%"=="static_md" (
if not "%LINK_MODE%"=="shared" (
if not "%LINK_MODE%"=="" (
if not "%LINK_MODE%"=="all" goto usage))))

rem Configuration [release|debug|both]
set CONFIGURATION=%4
if not "%CONFIGURATION%"=="release" (
if not "%CONFIGURATION%"=="debug" (
if not "%CONFIGURATION%"=="" (
if not "%CONFIGURATION%"=="both" goto usage)))

rem Platform [Win32|x64|WinCE]
set PLATFORM=%5%
if not "%PLATFORM%"=="" (
if not "%PLATFORM%"=="Win32" (
if not "%PLATFORM%"=="x64" (
if not "%PLATFORM%"=="WinCE" goto usage)))

if "%PLATFORM%"=="" (set PLATFORM_SUFFIX=) else (
if "%PLATFORM%"=="Win32" (set PLATFORM_SUFFIX=) else (
if "%PLATFORM%"=="x64" (set PLATFORM_SUFFIX=_x64) else (
if "%PLATFORM%"=="WinCE" (set PLATFORM_SUFFIX=_CE))))

rem Samples [samples|nosamples]
set SAMPLES=%6
if "%SAMPLES%"=="" (set SAMPLES=samples)

set DEBUG_SHARED=0
set RELEASE_SHARED=0
set DEBUG_STATIC_MT=0
set RELEASE_STATIC_MT=0
set DEBUG_STATIC_MD=0
set RELEASE_STATIC_MD=0

if "%LINK_MODE%"=="shared" (
if "%CONFIGURATION%"=="release" (set RELEASE_SHARED=1) else (
if "%CONFIGURATION%"=="both" (set RELEASE_SHARED=1) else (
if "%CONFIGURATION%"=="" (set RELEASE_SHARED=1))))

if "%LINK_MODE%"=="shared" (
if "%CONFIGURATION%"=="debug" (set DEBUG_SHARED=1) else (
if "%CONFIGURATION%"=="both" (set DEBUG_SHARED=1) else (
if "%CONFIGURATION%"=="" (set DEBUG_SHARED=1))))

if "%LINK_MODE%"=="static_mt" (
if "%CONFIGURATION%"=="release" (set RELEASE_STATIC_MT=1) else (
if "%CONFIGURATION%"=="both" (set RELEASE_STATIC_MT=1) else (
if "%CONFIGURATION%"=="" (set RELEASE_STATIC_MT=1))))

if "%LINK_MODE%"=="static_md" (
if "%CONFIGURATION%"=="release" (set RELEASE_STATIC_MD=1) else (
if "%CONFIGURATION%"=="both" (set RELEASE_STATIC_MD=1) else (
if "%CONFIGURATION%"=="" (set RELEASE_STATIC_MD=1))))

if "%LINK_MODE%"=="static_mt" (
if "%CONFIGURATION%"=="debug" (set DEBUG_STATIC_MT=1) else (
if "%CONFIGURATION%"=="both" (set DEBUG_STATIC_MT=1) else (
if "%CONFIGURATION%"=="" (set DEBUG_STATIC_MT=1))))

if "%LINK_MODE%"=="static_md" (
if "%CONFIGURATION%"=="debug" (set DEBUG_STATIC_MD=1) else (
if "%CONFIGURATION%"=="both" (set DEBUG_STATIC_MD=1) else (
if "%CONFIGURATION%"=="" (set DEBUG_STATIC_MD=1))))

if "%LINK_MODE%"=="all" (
if "%CONFIGURATION%"=="debug" (
set DEBUG_STATIC_MT=1
set DEBUG_STATIC_MD=1
set DEBUG_SHARED=1) else (
if "%CONFIGURATION%"=="release" (
set RELEASE_STATIC_MT=1
set RELEASE_STATIC_MD=1
set RELEASE_SHARED=1) else (
if "%CONFIGURATION%"=="both" (
set DEBUG_STATIC_MT=1
set DEBUG_STATIC_MD=1
set DEBUG_SHARED=1
set RELEASE_STATIC_MT=1
set RELEASE_STATIC_MD=1
set RELEASE_SHARED=1) else (
if "%CONFIGURATION%"=="" (
set DEBUG_STATIC_MT=1
set DEBUG_STATIC_MD=1
set DEBUG_SHARED=1
set RELEASE_STATIC_MT=1
set RELEASE_STATIC_MD=1
set RELEASE_SHARED=1)))))

if "%LINK_MODE%"=="" (
if "%CONFIGURATION%"=="debug" (
set DEBUG_STATIC_MT=1
set DEBUG_STATIC_MD=1
set DEBUG_SHARED=1) else (
if "%CONFIGURATION%"=="release" (
set RELEASE_STATIC_MT=1
set RELEASE_STATIC_MD=1
set RELEASE_SHARED=1) else (
if "%CONFIGURATION%"=="both" (
set DEBUG_STATIC_MT=1
set DEBUG_STATIC_MD=1
set DEBUG_SHARED=1
set RELEASE_STATIC_MT=1
set RELEASE_STATIC_MD=1
set RELEASE_SHARED=1) else (
if "%CONFIGURATION%"=="" (
set DEBUG_STATIC_MT=1
set DEBUG_STATIC_MD=1
set DEBUG_SHARED=1
set RELEASE_STATIC_MT=1
set RELEASE_STATIC_MD=1
set RELEASE_SHARED=1)))))

echo.
echo.
echo ########################################################################
echo ####
echo #### STARTING VISUAL STUDIO BUILD (%VS_VERSION%, %PLATFORM%)
echo ####
echo ########################################################################
echo.
echo.
echo The following configurations will be built:

if %DEBUG_SHARED%==1      (echo debug_shared)
if %RELEASE_SHARED%==1    (echo release_shared)
if %DEBUG_STATIC_MT%==1   (echo debug_static_mt)
if %DEBUG_STATIC_MD%==1   (echo debug_static_md)
if %RELEASE_STATIC_MT%==1 (echo release_static_mt)
if %RELEASE_STATIC_MD%==1 (echo release_static_md)

rem build for up to 4 levels deep
for /f %%G in ('findstr /R "." components') do (
 if exist %%G (
  cd %%G
  for /f "tokens=1,2,3,4 delims=/" %%Q in ("%%G") do (
   if exist %%Q%PLATFORM_SUFFIX%_%VS_VERSION%.sln (
    echo.
    echo.
    echo ########################################################################
    echo ####
    echo #### Building %%G
    echo ####
    echo ########################################################################
    echo.
    if %DEBUG_SHARED%==1      (%BUILD_TOOL% /useenv /%ACTION% debug_shared %%Q%PLATFORM_SUFFIX%_%VS_VERSION%.sln && echo. && echo. && echo.)
    if %RELEASE_SHARED%==1    (%BUILD_TOOL% /useenv /%ACTION% release_shared %%Q%PLATFORM_SUFFIX%_%VS_VERSION%.sln && echo. && echo. && echo.)
    if %DEBUG_STATIC_MT%==1   (%BUILD_TOOL% /useenv /%ACTION% debug_static_mt %%Q%PLATFORM_SUFFIX%_%VS_VERSION%.sln && echo. && echo. && echo.)
    if %RELEASE_STATIC_MT%==1 (%BUILD_TOOL% /useenv /%ACTION% release_static_mt %%Q%PLATFORM_SUFFIX%_%VS_VERSION%.sln && echo. && echo. && echo.)
    if %DEBUG_STATIC_MD%==1   (%BUILD_TOOL% /useenv /%ACTION% debug_static_md %%Q%PLATFORM_SUFFIX%_%VS_VERSION%.sln && echo. && echo. && echo.)
    if %RELEASE_STATIC_MD%==1 (%BUILD_TOOL% /useenv /%ACTION% release_static_md %%Q%PLATFORM_SUFFIX%_%VS_VERSION%.sln && echo. && echo. && echo.)
   )

   if exist %%R%PLATFORM_SUFFIX%_%VS_VERSION%.sln (
    echo.
    echo.
    echo ########################################################################
    echo ####
    echo #### Building %%G
    echo ####
    echo ########################################################################
    echo.
    if %DEBUG_SHARED%==1      (%BUILD_TOOL% /useenv /%ACTION% debug_shared %%R%PLATFORM_SUFFIX%_%VS_VERSION%.sln && echo. && echo. && echo.)
    if %RELEASE_SHARED%==1    (%BUILD_TOOL% /useenv /%ACTION% release_shared %%R%PLATFORM_SUFFIX%_%VS_VERSION%.sln && echo. && echo. && echo.)
    if %DEBUG_STATIC_MT%==1   (%BUILD_TOOL% /useenv /%ACTION% debug_static_mt %%R%PLATFORM_SUFFIX%_%VS_VERSION%.sln && echo. && echo. && echo.)
    if %RELEASE_STATIC_MT%==1 (%BUILD_TOOL% /useenv /%ACTION% release_static_mt %%R%PLATFORM_SUFFIX%_%VS_VERSION%.sln && echo. && echo. && echo.)
    if %DEBUG_STATIC_MD%==1   (%BUILD_TOOL% /useenv /%ACTION% debug_static_md %%R%PLATFORM_SUFFIX%_%VS_VERSION%.sln && echo. && echo. && echo.)
    if %RELEASE_STATIC_MD%==1 (%BUILD_TOOL% /useenv /%ACTION% release_static_md %%R%PLATFORM_SUFFIX%_%VS_VERSION%.sln && echo. && echo. && echo.)
   )

   if exist %%S%PLATFORM_SUFFIX%_%VS_VERSION%.sln (
    echo.
    echo.
    echo ########################################################################
    echo ####
    echo #### Building %%G
    echo ####
    echo ########################################################################
    echo.
    if %DEBUG_SHARED%==1      (%BUILD_TOOL% /useenv /%ACTION% debug_shared %%S%PLATFORM_SUFFIX%_%VS_VERSION%.sln && echo. && echo. && echo.)
    if %RELEASE_SHARED%==1    (%BUILD_TOOL% /useenv /%ACTION% release_shared %%S%PLATFORM_SUFFIX%_%VS_VERSION%.sln && echo. && echo. && echo.)
    if %DEBUG_STATIC_MT%==1   (%BUILD_TOOL% /useenv /%ACTION% debug_static_mt %%S%PLATFORM_SUFFIX%_%VS_VERSION%.sln && echo. && echo. && echo.)
    if %RELEASE_STATIC_MT%==1 (%BUILD_TOOL% /useenv /%ACTION% release_static_mt %%S%PLATFORM_SUFFIX%_%VS_VERSION%.sln && echo. && echo. && echo.)
    if %DEBUG_STATIC_MD%==1   (%BUILD_TOOL% /useenv /%ACTION% debug_static_md %%S%PLATFORM_SUFFIX%_%VS_VERSION%.sln && echo. && echo. && echo.)
    if %RELEASE_STATIC_MD%==1 (%BUILD_TOOL% /useenv /%ACTION% release_static_md %%S%PLATFORM_SUFFIX%_%VS_VERSION%.sln && echo. && echo. && echo.)
   )

   if exist %%T%PLATFORM_SUFFIX%_%VS_VERSION%.sln (
    echo.
    echo.
    echo ########################################################################
    echo ####
    echo #### Building %%G
    echo ####
    echo ########################################################################
    echo.
    if %DEBUG_SHARED%==1      (%BUILD_TOOL% /useenv /%ACTION% debug_shared %%T%PLATFORM_SUFFIX%_%VS_VERSION%.sln && echo. && echo. && echo.)
    if %RELEASE_SHARED%==1    (%BUILD_TOOL% /useenv /%ACTION% release_shared %%T%PLATFORM_SUFFIX%_%VS_VERSION%.sln && echo. && echo. && echo.)
    if %DEBUG_STATIC_MT%==1   (%BUILD_TOOL% /useenv /%ACTION% debug_static_mt %%T%PLATFORM_SUFFIX%_%VS_VERSION%.sln && echo. && echo. && echo.)
    if %RELEASE_STATIC_MT%==1 (%BUILD_TOOL% /useenv /%ACTION% release_static_mt %%T%PLATFORM_SUFFIX%_%VS_VERSION%.sln && echo. && echo. && echo.)
    if %DEBUG_STATIC_MD%==1   (%BUILD_TOOL% /useenv /%ACTION% debug_static_md %%T%PLATFORM_SUFFIX%_%VS_VERSION%.sln && echo. && echo. && echo.)
    if %RELEASE_STATIC_MD%==1 (%BUILD_TOOL% /useenv /%ACTION% release_static_md %%T%PLATFORM_SUFFIX%_%VS_VERSION%.sln && echo. && echo. && echo.)
   )
  )
  cd %POCO_BASE%
 )
)

if "%SAMPLES%"=="no" goto :EOF

rem root level component samples
for /f %%G in ('findstr /R "." components') do (
 if exist %%G\samples\samples%PLATFORM_SUFFIX%_%VS_VERSION%.sln (
  cd %%G\samples
    echo.
    echo.
    echo ########################################################################
    echo ####
    echo #### Building %%G/samples
    echo ####
    echo ########################################################################
    echo.
  if %DEBUG_SHARED%==1      (%BUILD_TOOL% /useenv /%ACTION% debug_shared samples%PLATFORM_SUFFIX%_%VS_VERSION%.sln && echo. && echo. && echo.)
  if %RELEASE_SHARED%==1    (%BUILD_TOOL% /useenv /%ACTION% release_shared samples%PLATFORM_SUFFIX%_%VS_VERSION%.sln && echo. && echo. && echo.)
  if %DEBUG_STATIC_MT%==1   (%BUILD_TOOL% /useenv /%ACTION% debug_static_mt samples%PLATFORM_SUFFIX%_%VS_VERSION%.sln && echo. && echo. && echo.)
  if %RELEASE_STATIC_MT%==1 (%BUILD_TOOL% /useenv /%ACTION% release_static_mt samples%PLATFORM_SUFFIX%_%VS_VERSION%.sln && echo. && echo. && echo.)
  if %DEBUG_STATIC_MD%==1   (%BUILD_TOOL% /useenv /%ACTION% debug_static_md samples%PLATFORM_SUFFIX%_%VS_VERSION%.sln && echo. && echo. && echo.)
  if %RELEASE_STATIC_MD%==1 (%BUILD_TOOL% /useenv /%ACTION% release_static_md samples%PLATFORM_SUFFIX%_%VS_VERSION%.sln && echo. && echo. && echo.)
  cd %POCO_BASE%
 )
)

goto :EOF

:usage
echo Usage:
echo ------
echo buildwin VS_VERSION [ACTION] [LINKMODE] [CONFIGURATION] [PLATFORM] [SAMPLES] [DEVENV]
echo VS_VERSION: "71|80|90|100"
echo ACTION:     "build|rebuild|clean"
echo LINKMODE:   "static_mt|static_md|shared|all"
echo CONFIG:     "release|debug|both"
echo PLATFORM:   "Win32|x64|WinCE"
echo SAMPLES:    "samples|nosamples"
echo DEVENV:     "devenv|vcexpress"
echo.
echo Default is build all.
endlocal
```

Does anyone know specifically which Devenv I should be replacing?

Comment: Do you really need to build it via the build file? If we're talking about the same Poco, it comes with Visual Studio project files for all versions up to 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First have a look on following:-

> echo Usage:
>   .......
>   **echo DEVENV:     "devenv|vcexpress"**

```
if "%7"=="" goto use_devenv
set BUILD_TOOL="%7"
goto use_custom
:use_devenv
set BUILD_TOOL=vcexpress
:use_custom
```

Now you can see the usage script clearly mentions that BUILD TOOL should either be vcexpress or devenv.

This batch is already configured to start build with vcexpress edition.So you dont need to worry before using it.